# I am having trouble to invoke idf.py command from windows shell

Tags: esp32

I am trying to run the following command as suggested by the espressif documentation, but I get a message saying ***'Please use idf.py only in an ESP-IDF shell environment.'***

`..\esp\esp-idf\examples\get-started\hello_world> idf.py set-target esp32`

Do you have an idea about what could have done wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The instructions are here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/windows-setup.html